# Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED check after every battry percentage decay

Tags: android

I want to implement the battery percentage alert when battery  level goes to 15% of mobile,So i Have implemented the service for this just because of my application is not in foreground.and this service runs in background.and inside the service my reciever runs.
    But problem is my service stops and to check the battery percentage also kills.
     Please suggest some solution if somes1 has

Comment: Why not you read http://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/battery-monitoring.html.  There is no use to register and use receiver into service.

Comment: I have used it same ,and register reciever dynamically,but what will happen when my app not presents in background

Comment: Register you receiver statically.

Comment: static registeration can not give the value of every percentage change in battery level.static can only for Action_battey_low.